# how to capture shopify webhook payload to use for local development?

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I'm trying to write a few azure functions which will do some reasonably simple integrations after a Shopify order sends a webhook.

I've got a conceptual issue that I'd appreciate some help with.

I'm trying to mock up the webhook in Postman. to do this, I used Hookbin to collect the output from Shopify and the body came through a little like this

```
{
  "id": 3207753990315,
  "email": "mattshort77@gmail.com",
  "closed_at": null,
  "created_at": "2021-02-02T21:44:18+00:00",
  "updated_at": "2021-02-02T21:44:19+00:00",
  "number": 28,
  "note": "",
  "total_price": "10.00",\
  ....
}
```

I think that this is json formatted.
so i took this from hookbin and put it into the body (raw) of a postman call. using the local address for the azure function. (which i'm coding in VS Code on a mac). When i send this it works fine. In the function i can collect the $Request.Body and convert from JSON format.

The problem comes in when i promote my function to azure.
An Azure Function receives a custom object in as $Request, so the convert from JSON line isnt needed.

I need to understand how to mock the JSON that ive got from Hookbin up into the same format as the object that the function receives as this would speed up my dev flow loads. and just be a better pattern to be fair. I'm realitvely sure that this is the step I've got wrong. In collecting the payload with Hookbin, I've got the JSON format of the order, but thats not how its received in an Azure Function, which according to the documention presents the $Request as on object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty of the Azure Functions host is that you don't need to worry about converting the JSON yourself (depending on how your Postman request is constructed.

For example here I am using POST method to send to my function with a JSON payload.

[image: Insomnia API POST Example to Azure Functions running locally]

If a `POST` method is used against your function then that will automatically be populated in `$Request.Body` whereas if you use `GET` it will automatically populate `$Request.Query`

The JSON object is serialised for you so that you don't need to convert from JSON inside your function.

My function looks like below:

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param (
    $Request,
    $TriggerMetadata
)

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$deserializedObject = $Request.Body

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value (
    [HttpResponseContext]@{
        StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
        Body = $deserializedObject
    }
)
```

And debugging that function to inspect the value as it's passed in you can see that it's automatically converted to a hashtable without me having to call `ConvertFrom-Json` inside my function.

[image: Debugging Azure function locally in VSCode]

And you can see that I didn't have to use `ConvertTo-Json` to output my results to `Push-OutputBinding` either and the returned value in Insomnia is JSON.

[image: Output of calling local Azure Function inside Insomnia Application]

I am not sure how you have your local environment setup for testing but using the Function Core Tools should allow you to run and execute the functions locally and it should be the same as it is executed in Azure.

Comment: i had a combination of issues, but you covered them in here. I was using a mixture of post and get queries. but also i wasn't sending valid json across the board from postman. thanks for posting, ive got a much better dev flow now.

Answer (score 0):

`$Request.RawBody` may give you what you need.

Comment: It is recommended if you can add more details to this text qualify as answer, so that other users can get learning/benefit from this as well.